# ReactJS: undefined is not an object in Safari

Tags: javascript, reactjs, safari

Came across a weird bug today that only happens on Safari. Works fine on Chrome and Firefox, but not Safari.

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'wo.strDescription.toLowerCase')
```

That's the error.

This is my function:

```
const SimulateFind = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const q = e.target.searchbox.value;
  let res = orders.filter(wo => wo.strDescription.toLowerCase().includes(q));
  setWorkOrdersEdit(res);
}
```

I would love some advice.

Thanks!

Comment: undefined is not an object in any context. You'll need to show the structure of `orders`, and also indicate when `SimulateFind` is called.

Comment: No, but it's not Undefined... When i console log(orders) above it, it gives the correct data. Hence, this is only happening in Safari and not Chrome.